# How to pause audio recording in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, audio-recording, xamarin.uwp

I am creating an audio recorder app. I am using plugin.AudioRecorder library to record the audio. Its working fine while continuous recording. But now I need to implement the pause functionality in it. But not able to pause the recording. 
What can I do to pause the audio recording in xamarin forms?

I am not getting anything for pause functionality so now I am trying to merge muliple recordings. Means at pause I stop the recording and get its byte array then I start recording again and when pause it I get its byte array also and merge it. 
The file get merge successfully but when I am playing it, it plays only latest recording only. 
What might be the issue in this case?

Comment: have you tried calling StopRecording and then StartRecording again?

Comment: https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder/issues/12

Comment: @Jason yes I tried to stoprecording and then startrecording, It stores only latest recording only